# How to link a directory in Ubuntu to a directory in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

I've just installed Ubuntu 10.04, trying out linux for the first time. I'm wondering if it's possible to link my documents folder in Ubuntu to my documents folder in Windows, so that when I open the folder in Ubuntu, I am linked to the folder in Windows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
cd ~
mv Documents Documents.orig
ln -s "/path/to/My Documents" Documents
```

Comment: That works only if the Windows partition is mounted under Linux. Use the command "mount" (no arguments) to see if and where it is mounted.

Comment: If its not automatically mounted, you can always edit your fstab file to mount the windows partition every time you boot up. see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab for info on fstab.